# R loop between multiple data.frames and assign values to them

Tags: r, loops

I'm using **R** to perform some alterations in cnvkit output (for my purposes). The thing is: doing the job sample by sample, the script works like a charm but, when I put it into a for loop, it breaks!

Tried a lot of answers posted on Stack Overflow but none of then helped me.

```
# Clear workspace
rm(list=(ls()))

ref <- read.csv("/path/to/reference.cnn", header=T, sep="\t")
path <- "/path/to/call_files/"
files = list.files(path = path, pattern = "*.final.call.cnr", full.names=FALSE)
for(file in files) {
    perpos <- which(strsplit(file, "")[[1]]==".")
    assign(
    gsub(" ","",substr(file, 1, perpos-1)), 
    read.csv(paste(path,file,sep=""), header=T, sep="\t"))

}


mod_CNV = function(x) {

    # Merge both files by "start" position
    merged <- merge(files[i], ref, by="start", suffixes=c(".files[i]", ".ref"))

    # Round "log2" column
    merged$log2.D00893 <- round(merged$log2.files[i], digits=1)

    # re-calculate "cn" based on log2 correction
    merged$cn <- round(2*(2^(merged$log2.files[i])))

    # Subset file with all "cn" values that are not 2
    alt.cn <- subset(merged, merged$cn !=2)

    # Create new data with columns of interest
    alt.cns <- as.data.frame(alt.cn[, c(1:8,13)])

    # Re-order columns for better view
    alt.cns <- alt.cns[c(2,1,3,4,6,5,8,7,9)]

    # Calculate ratio between coverages
    alt.cns$depth.ratio <- round(alt.cns$depth.files[i] / alt.cns$depth.ref, digits=2)
    alt.cns$depth.ratio.1 <- round(alt.cns$depth.files[i] / alt.cns$depth.ref, digits=2)

    ## Function to call for DUP or DEL.  
    alt.cns$SV_type <- ifelse(alt.cns$cn < 2, "DEL", "DUP")

    # Convert "alt.cns" to .bed file
    full <- alt.cns[c(1,2,3,12,5,4,6,7,8,9,10)]
    names(full)[1] <- "#Chrom"
    names(full)[2] <- "Start"
    names(full)[3] <- "End"
    names(full)[4] <- "SV_type"
    names(full)[6] <- "gene"
    names(full)[7] <- "log2"

    # Save "alt.cns" as .bed file
    write.table(full, file="/path/to/output/files[i].bed", row.names=F, col.names=T, sep="\t")

    # Filter "alt.cns" file
    filtered <- subset(alt.cns, alt.cns$depth.ratio < 0.70 | alt.cns$depth.ratio > 1.40 & alt.cns$weight > 0.3)
    filtered <- filtered[c(1,2,3,12,5,4,6,7,8,9,10)]
    names(filtered)[1] <- "#Chrom"
    names(filtered)[2] <- "Start"
    names(filtered)[3] <- "End"
    names(filtered)[4] <- "SV_type"
    names(filtered)[6] <- "gene"
    names(filtered)[7] <- "log2"

    #Save file
    write.table(filtered, file="/path/to/output/files[i].bed", row.names=F, col.names=T, sep="\t")

}


for ( i in seq_along(files)) {
        mod_CNV(files[i])
    }
```

What I expect is that the loop reads file by file and assign each individual file name to variables `files[i]` and save as .pdf. But, I'm getting a error right on the beginning of the code:

> "Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column".

For some reason, the loop isn't recognizing my `files[i]` variable, which is causing this error. Can someone help me in this problem?
To be clear, this error doesn't occur when running sample by sample, out of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who falls on the same problem as I, there goes the right code:

```
path <- "/path/to/files/"
files = list.files(path = path, pattern = "*.file.ext", full.names=FALSE)
for(file in files) {
    perpos <- which(strsplit(file, "")[[1]]==".")
    assign(
    gsub(" ","",substr(file, 1, perpos-1)), 
    read.csv(paste(path,file,sep=""), header=T, sep="\t"))

}

s_ref <- read.csv("/read/ref/file", header=T, sep="\t")
s_ref["depth.ref.norm"] <- round(s_ref["depth"]/mean(s_ref[["depth"]]), digits=2)

mod_CNV = function(file) {
    file_df <- read.csv(file, header=T, sep="\t")

    # Normalize $depth by mean
    file_df[sprintf("depth.%s.norm", file)] <- round(file_df[["depth"]]/mean(file_df[["depth"]]), digits=2)

    # Merge both files by "start" position
    merged <- merge(file_df, s_ref, by="start", suffixes=c(sprintf(".%s", file), ".ref"), all=TRUE)

    # Round "log2" column
    log2_col_name = sprintf("log2.%s", file)
    merged[log2_col_name] <- round(merged[[log2_col_name]], digits=1)

    # re-calculate "cn" based on log2 correction
    merged["cn"] <- round(2*(2^(merged[[log2_col_name]])))

    # Subset file with all "cn" values that are not 2
    alt_cn <- subset(merged, merged[["cn"]] != 2)

    # Create new data with columns of interest
    alt_cns <- as.data.frame(alt_cn[, c(1:9,14,18)])

    # Re-order columns for better view
    alt_cns <- alt_cns[c(2,1,3,4,6,5,8,7,9,10,11)]

    # Calculate ratio between coverages
    alt_cns["depth.ratio.norm"] <- round(alt_cns[[sprintf("depth.%s.norm", file)]] / alt_cns[["depth.ref.norm"]], digits=2)

    alt_cns["depth.ratio"] <- round(alt_cns[[sprintf("depth.%s", file)]] / alt_cns[["depth.ref"]], digits=2)

    ## Function to call for DUP or DEL.  
    alt_cns["SV_type"] <- ifelse(alt_cns$cn < 2, "DEL", "AMP")

    # Convert "alt.cns" to .bed file
    full <- alt_cns[c(1,2,3,14,5,4,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13)]
    names(full)[1] <- "#Chrom"
    names(full)[2] <- "Start"
    names(full)[3] <- "End"
    names(full)[4] <- "SV_type"
    names(full)[6] <- "gene"
    names(full)[7] <- "log2"

    full["weight"] <- round(full[["weight"]], digits = 2)
    full <- full[order(full$"#Chrom"),]

    # Save "full" as .bed file
    output_file = sprintf("/path/%s.bed", file)
    write.table(full, file=output_file, row.names=F, col.names=T, sep="\t", dec=",")

}
    print(files)
    for (file in files) {
        mod_CNV(file)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

You've declared a function:

```
mod_CNV = function(x) {

    # Merge both files by "start" position
    merged <- merge(files[i], ref, by="start", suffixes=c(".files[i]", ".ref"))
    .
    .
    .
}
```

From what I can tell, there is no reason that this function should know what `i` is; this is probably why `files[i]` fails.

Here is where `i` is located

```
for ( i in seq_along(files)) {
    mod_CNV(files[i])
}
```

`i` is a variable that is local to the `for` loop. If you want it to be available inside mod_CNV, you'd need to pass it in as a parameter.

What you are passing in to `mod_CNV` is the filename. Inside of `mod_CNV`, this filename is referred to as `x` yet I don't see anywhere inside `mod_CNV` where you use `x`.

This is how you should declare your function and make use of the filename you are passing in:

```
mod_CNV = function(filename) {

    # Merge both files by "start" position
    merged <- merge(filename, ref, by="start", suffixes=c(filename, ".ref"))
    .
    .
    .
    # replace all other occurrences of `file[i]` with `filename`
}
```

And you can loop through the list of files and call `mod_CNV` like this, without using `i`:

```
for (file in files) {
    mod_CNV(file)
}
```

Also, I haven't used `merge` before and I don't know exactly what you are trying to do... but I find it odd to use an entire filename as a suffix. But it may be what you intended.

Anyway, this should be enough information for you to resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've made the modifications on my script but I'm still getting the same error on the 'merge' step... I'm going to look for another way to merge files! Thanks.

Comment: I just realized I forgot the "." in suffixes. It should have been `suffixes=c(paste0(".", filename), ".ref")`. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help and sorry for not answering before. Unfortunately, your answer was not correct. So, I've found the solution. I will post the right code bellow!